# I can't get my html to execute my js file on Electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I might be really bad at this but I've spent the last two hours on it so if someone could indicate me what's wrong I would be eternally grateful.

I am training on Electron and I am trying to make this game, Visual Novel style, that features dialogs, pictures and minigames. I am trying to set up the dialogs so that they may switch when the player presses "Space". To do that, I created a js file and tried to set it up, and I think the code should be working, but nothing happens when I press space... My best guess is that the app doesnt recognize the js file even tho the pathing should be good !
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="blanche.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    />
  </head>
  <body tabindex="0">
    <section class="sprite">
      <h1>sprite</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="score">
      <h1>score</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="dialog" id="dialog">
      <p id="text" class="text">Défaut</p>
    </section>

    <section class="loading">
      <h1>loading</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="rps">
      <h1>rps</h1>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    }
    h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 42% 5% 25% 3% 25%;
    gap: 0;
    }

    .sprite{
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    .score{
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    }

    .dialog{
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(56, 53, 53);
    }

    .text{
    color: green;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    }

    .loading{
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    }

    .rps{
    border-top: 3px black solid;

    }
```

JS:

```js
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
let dialogueIndex = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (event.code === "Space") {
    dialogueIndex++;

    switch (dialogueIndex) {
      case 1:
        text.innerHTML = "Je vais bien, merci ! Et toi ?";
        break;
      case 2:
        text.innerHTML = "Je vais bien aussi, merci !";
        break;
      case 3:
        dialog.style.display = "none";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

I tried showing a console log at the very beginning of the js file, nothing happened. I verified the names of my files and their pathing 10 times, nothing looks wrong...

Comment: Did you check in the network tab of the devtools that it is fetching the right files?

Comment: I did! It shows correctly. That being said, it shows a message in the console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (blanche.js:12:24) I didnt see it the first time around because (naive as I am) I thought the electron console was the only one to check...

Answer (score 1):

Solved, thank you ! I didnt see the message in the right console, in fact my js was trying to execute before my html was fully loaded, and so, my code couldn't target the element that didnt exist yet. As a solution, I added a window.onload = function() condition with my js, so that it would only activate once the page is loaded. thank you for helping !